# Trying to find a particular login Form which pops up randomly in my Magento 2 website

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Trying to find a particular login Form which pops up randomly in my Magento 2 website, please check the screenshot below.

[image]

I have enabled path hint, but not getting its location, any other way to find this file.. please let me know

Comment: Which theme you are using ?

Comment: @Ranganathan Claue Theme..